# Running more node.js applications with different arguments on AWS Stack

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, puppeteer, serverless

I have node.js application, which I would like to run many times, each day on scheduled time with different arguments.

Condition: Usage of AWS stack

Example: Each day run at 7 p.m. Run 10 times the same app using different arguments for each.

Currently I am using basic set-up of one EC2, pm2, running the node.js app with different arguments.

What I would like to achieve is to use more serverless infrastructure, with separate computing power. I am using puppeteer in my app so sharing e.g. 10 processes on one machine is problem sometimes.

I am looking for advice what AWS service is best for my usage (Elastic Beanstalk, ECS, AWS Lambda) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application exit after a ***particular time then serverless*** will work well in this situation.

I will suggest two option

- [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/)
- AWS lambda

If we look into fargate, All you need different task definition and **single Docker image** for all your dozen application plus you can run the application for more then fifteen minutes with fargate that is not possible with lambda.

So all you need to design Dockerfile in way that It accepts `CMD` and you can pass an argument to nodejs process.

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache curl
WORKDIR /app
RUN curl -o app.js https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Adiii717/94543c1f87e6db86b55ba3a5a58a2bbc/raw/da0695811b50d70be4c36951e5baa40a051a2dcf/app.js
RUN echo $'#!/bin/sh \n\ 
     node app.js \"${@}\"  ' >> /bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /bin/entrypoint.sh
entrypoint ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

So to run N service with this Dockefile base on argument

```
docker run -it --rm abc app1
docker run -it --rm abc app2
docker run -it --rm abc app3
.
.
.
```

In task definition you will need to pass just

```
"command": ["app1"]

"command": ["app2"]
```

> Example: Each day run at 7 p.m. Run 10 times the same app using
> different arguments for each.

Define cloud watch rule to trigger desired fargate task base on time.

[scheduled_tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html)

> I want to save money for time when no process is running.

You will only pay when the process/tasks is running.

Comment: Thanks for advice, AWS Fargate looks like solutions for me! This helped me a lot! Another reason why it looks like it's suitable for me, that my processess last longer than 15 minutes....

Comment: Yes its suitable for such job

Comment: One more question, what if the processes uses redis. Can I run redis in separate container and make the other processes use that ? How?

Comment: Yes you can run Redis container, and connect with Redis using service discovery

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ec2 instance for this task you can use cron

```
sudo apt install cron
```

In it you can schedule the tasks. for more info you can visit

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html)

But if you are saying you wish to go server-less then you can use lambdas and cloud watch that will trigger event after time that you set it. for more info you can visit

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html)

Lambda's are cheap too.

Comment: I am using the first option you've mentioned (ec2 ubuntu machine + cron jobs). Reason why I want to move to something like Lambda, that I want to save money for time when no process is running.